# Fetch USDZ / USD file from flask python not working on safari

Tags: flask, usdz

I have a server running a basic Flask server with send_file to allow a USDZ file to be downloaded
when fetching the endpoint:

```
@app.route("/make_usd", methods=['GET'])
def make_usd():
    data = usd.create_usd(1, 2, 0.05)
    response = make_response(send_file(data["url"], mimetype="model/vnd.usdz+zip", attachment_filename=data["url"], as_attachment=True))
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"
    return response
```

This works perfectly on Chrome, when fetching `http://0.0.0.0:9090/make_usd` the file is downloaded ok.

On safari I get "safari unable to open page"

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when fetching http://0.0.0.0:9090/make_usd

Why you use `0.0.0.0`? If you want to access service locally hosted on the machine you work on? Then use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead.